# What is EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=2, address=0x16f39fff8)?

Tags: swift, xcode, swiftui, exc-bad-access, appdelegate

My app builds successfully, but when it starts running I get this error:`Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=2, address=0x16f39fff8)`. Does anyone know what it could be in connection with? I deleted the code which I wrote before this error and it didn't help. I am a beginner so sorry if I asked a stupid question. Thanks for your attention. I’m looking forward to your reply.

Comment: Show backtrace - `(lldb) bt all`

Comment: This error could mean anything pretty much. Are you using source control? If so try comparing which lines you changed and see which ones cause the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I didn't write a dot before padding. It was a bad mistake. I just don't understand why it didn't give me an error while building.